# Postman says 403 forbidden when i register

Tags: laravel, postman

It works perfectly fine when I tested my API last month, but when I tested it again today it says 403 forbidden when I tried to register.

[image]

Here is the UserController :

```
public function register(Request $request)
 {
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'name' => 'required',

         'email' => 'required|unique:users',

         'password' => 'required|min:6',
     ], [
         'name.required' => 'The first name field is required.',
         'email.required' => 'The last name field is required.',
     ]);

     if ($validator->fails()) {
         return response()->json(['errors' => "Couldn't validate"], 403);
     }
     $user = User::create([
         'name' => $request->name,

         'email' => $request->email,

         'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
     ]);

     $token = $user->createToken('RestaurantCustomerAuth')->accessToken;


     return response()->json(['token' => $token, 'name'=>$user->name ], 200);
 }
```

Comment: validation failed ... how about you return the validation errors so you can see why its failing

Comment: 403 is the wrong status code to use for this. 400 seems a better fit

Comment: but why are you passing post body parameters as query parameter instead?!

Answer (score 0):

Try  `'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',`